# How does Spring Boot client app call Config Server in "Azure Spring Apps"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server, azure-spring-cloud

I am researching using the managed Spring Cloud Config Server in Azure Spring Apps. I don't believe my organization is using Azure Spring Apps yet, so I have no experience with it. I've read all the MS documentation that I could find about setting up to use Spring Cloud Config Server. I also read a couple of non-MS tutorials. But I have not read anything regarding these:

1. How is the client Spring App configured to reach the Config Server? I saw no specific mention of that. However, I do see that the `spring.config.import` property is automatically injected to the client. Is that how the URI is provided?
2. What is used on ConfigServer side to authenticate incoming requests from the client Spring apps? If none by default (which is extremely likely), is there a way to inject authentication layer? Is authentication considered to not be needed because the Config Server is only reachable by the other apps running in your Azure Spring Apps instance?
3. Would it be doable and reasonable to set up Config Server in Azure Spring Apps, then have external Spring apps (running in K8s or Azure VM) access it? That could allow for easier management of the Config Server and allow for migrating apps to Azure Spring Apps in an iterative manner instead of big bang.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-prepare-app-deployment?tabs=basic-standard-tier&pivots=programming-language-java#distributed-configuration). In general, you only need to include the config server client starter.
2. Azure Spring Apps platform will take care of authentication.
3. You can do it yourselves for sure. However, it is also supported to let apps external Spring Apps instance to visit Config Server by some extra steps. Please check [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-access-data-plane-azure-ad-rbac#register-spring-boot-apps-to-spring-cloud-config-server-and-service-registry-managed-by-azure-spring-apps) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the info. This is helpful, but does not completely answer my questions.

1. I had read that document. It tells you how to set it up, but doesn't explain how it works. I need to know how it works in order to be able to support it and troubleshoot it.
2. I would have to go to our security architect and explain how authentication works in order to get this approved. They would need more details than just that it takes care of it.
3. Thank you. (I don't quite understand how it works, but it seems to be referencing this scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using Enterprise tier, Configuration service is managed by Tanzu Application Configuration Service. You can make entries in Tanzu Config Service through Azure portal or Azure CLI and each entry is tied down to a config pattern. During deployment, you have the option to use any pattern that you have configured to be used as part of app deployment. There is no need to pass any spring boot properties as part of your deployment. More Info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-apps/how-to-enterprise-application-configuration-service?tabs=Portal
2. If you using Github to store your config, you need to configure your Config server to authenticate via Github personal token(which you need to provide in Tanzu Configuration Service)
3. It is perfectly doable and reasonable and very easy to manage

Comment: As for #1, thank you for the information. This helps for Enterprise tier, but does not explain how the client "knows" how to reach the config server in Basic tier. For #2, I was talking about the client app authenticating to the config server, not the config server authenticating to the Github server. #3 Since I still don't know how a client app is set up with a config server URI, I wouldn't know how to set up a non-Azure-Spring-Apps client to call the configserver running in Azure Spring Apps. Can you provide more information about how one would set this up? (That would also help explain #1.)